# Angular prod mode No component factory found error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am developing angular application that version is 8.3. The application is working o development mode. But I have a dynamic component create using following command.

```
  getComponentFactory(name: string, resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    const factories = Array.from<any>(resolver['_factories'].keys());

    const factoryClass = <Type<any>>factories.find((item: any) => item.name === name);

    return resolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);
  }
```

This method finds the component that name is equals to `name` parameter. But whan I build application in --prod mode

`ng build --prod --base-href="//"`

The application throws error:

> Error: No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to
> @NgModule.entryComponents?

I think the application prod mode uglifies the component name, but my component name parameter is not uglified.

How can I solve this issue? Can I use do not uglify the component names?

Comment: check your `app.module.ts` see if the component is imported there and also in declaration array

Comment: yes it is imported, declared and entry components.